# How to return no answer with nginx?

Tags: nginx, cdn

I use nginx with Incapsula CDN and need to cleanly block all another requests in nginx's server {} context (for certain domain names, but not for all nginx's connections). Best practice in my opinion is return no answer, if client IP not in Incapsula's ranges, like a webserver who has no configuration for this domain. How can I do it ?

Comment: Exactly which error do you want to return?

Comment: Do you wanna talk about it?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `return 444;` for connection reset without answer.

[The non-standard code 444 closes a connection without sending a response header.](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#return)

Answer (score 0):

If you're only ever going to accept connections from your CDN's netblocks, why even let the request get to your webserver? Set a default deny policy in iptables, and then allow connections from the CDN.

Comment: What happens when the CDN gets new IP addresses?

Comment: Update the iptables rules - no different than sending a specific type of request via Nginx. Those rules would need to be updated as well.

Comment: Yes, this works, but then you have visitors getting errors during the interim.

Comment: Well again, the same thing would happen either way.